# ios bar button item on a table view controller

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

I am new to ios programming working on my first app. I have a tab bar controller with two tabs A and B. Both tabs are connected to table view controller with some data being shown. I want to add a bar button item on the top left "navigation" bar of the table. This would be a slide bar menu navigation item as shown in figure below
[image]

However, even though in my storyboard the menu bar button item shows up (as shown in the pic), when I run the program, the table corresponding to tab "A" that gets displayed does not show the menu item.

**UPDATE:** Solution (see the marked answer and comments) -Basically, you need to embed the table view controller in navigation view controller, set "Top bar" to "Navigation Bar" and then you can add a bar button item.

**UPDATE 2** - Setting the top bar to "Navigation Bar" in attributes of the table view controller is optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of inserting the bar button in the tab view controller insert it in view controller "A."

Comment: Thanks for a super fast response! Tried that already but can not. When I do that the bar button item goes in the bottom and when I run the program.

Comment: Did you insert a navigation bar in your view controller A?

Comment: You cant. But you can choose to configure so the top bar is "navigation bar". Does not help though.

Comment: Embed your view controller A with an Navigation Controller.To do that select you view controller A and  select editor -> embed in -> navigation controller.

Comment: I just did that - and you beat me to the response :) Will mark your answer as correct. Basically, you need to embed the table view controller in navigation view controller, set "Top bar" to "Navigation Bar" and then you can add a bar button item. Thanks!